# How do I keep my button which is a <a class="button">LEARN MORE</a> centered when I break under 600px?

Tags: button

My email looks good using tables, but when I shrink the screen to see what it would look like on mobile my button always slides off center. Can anyone help me?

I tried `text-align:center;` and `width:50%;` and `margin:0 auto;` and nothing seems to be working.